# Reference request: hedging options and The Greeks

Tags: reference-request

I am reading a math-heavy book on option pricing in cont-time, but I am embarrassed to say that I have little intuition of how hedging works in practice, how the Greeks are used,  and so on.

What's a good reference for hedging strategies which is practical but not...  "soft",  like say Investopedia?

Comment: Always good to read (or re-read) Hull's option book - either the light version ("Introduction to...") of the normal one.

Comment: @noob2 - all true, but OP is asking about references, not about what greeks and/or hedging is.

Comment: Taleb's "Dynamic Hedging - Managing Vanilla and Exotic Options" is a good reference.

Comment: I like the books of euan sinclair. Also, if you're really new to option trading maybe the books of Frans de Weert, although they are very basic.

Comment: my books Concepts and Practice of Mathematical FInance and More Mathematical Finance try to strike a mid-level with maths but also discussion of how things works.